# Reactjs, state, className

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I´m creating a menu that changes his styles when I scroll, but...

this is part of my header.js:(it has to be a class..)

...

```
render(){
return(
   <header className={`${this.classHeader}`}>
      <nav>
        <div>
          <ul>{this.navigationItems.items.map((item,i)=><NavItem key={i} data={item} />)}</ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
   </header>
)}}
```

and this is mi AppHolder.js:

```
class AppHolder extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
      this.state={
        one:'navBar'
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
     window.onscroll = () => this.handleAnimation()
  }

  handleAnimation = () => {
    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100){
      this.setState({
        one:'scroll'
      })
    }
    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop === 0 ){
      this.setState({
        one:'navBar'
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
         <Header classHeader={this.state.one}/>
         <MainContent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

but..in the HTML...

```
<header class="undefined"></header>
```

I also imported the styles in each component for the corresponding classes

my questions are...why? and how can I fix this? for the class to change when I scroll

thanks! and sorry for my poor english.. greetings from Argentina

Comment: `<header className={\`${this.classHeader}\`}>` should be `<header className={this.props.classHeader}>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the props keyword in the header render method... `<header className={this.props.classHeader}>` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Evrytime you pass a property like `classHeader` to a component, will be accesible from the current context on a variable called `props`.

In your example is something like this:

```
const { classHeader } = this.props;
```

So, what you need to do is consume from that property on the `Header` component like this:

```
render(){
const { classHeader } = this.props;
return(
   <header className={`${classHeader}`}>
      <nav>
        <div>
          <ul>{this.navigationItems.items.map((item,i)=><NavItem key={i} data={item} />)}</ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
   </header>
)}}
```

Comment: this works as well, using destructuring assignment, thanks!